# ASP.Net MVC2 (RTM) breaks response filtering - "Filtering is not allowed"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, httpresponse

I've just done a test run of upgrading a project to ASP.Net MVC 2 (RTM) in anticipation of the full official .Net 4.0 release coming later this month.

Our application is using a minimizer for our CSS and javascript.  To do so, it is making use of the `HttpResponse.Filter` property to set a custom filter.

With the upgrade, the setter for this property is throwing an `HttpException` saying "Filtering is not allowed."  Looking that the `HttpResponse.Filter` property in reflector shows this:

```
  set
    {
        if (!this.UsingHttpWriter)
        {
            throw new HttpException(SR.GetString("Filtering_not_allowed"));
        }
```

...

```
private bool UsingHttpWriter
{
    get
    {
        return ((this._httpWriter != null) && (this._writer == this._httpWriter));
    }
}
```

Clearly something has changed in the way the HttpResponse is writing to the output stream in MVC2.  Does anyone know what the change is, or at least a workaround for this?

**EDIT:**  This seems pretty radical.  Some further investigation shows that ASP.Net MVC 2 RTM is using a `System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage.SwitchWriter` as the Output property of an `HttpResponse`, whereas MVC 1 was using a plain old `HttpWriter`.  That explains why the exception is being thrown.

But that doesn't explain why they've chosen to completely break this functionality.  [This thread](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=5466) seems to indicate that this is just temporary... but this makes me pretty nervous... this is the RTM after all.

Any further comments appreciated on this.

Comment: For what it's worth, MVC 2 RTM has already been released: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c9ba1fe1-3ba8-439a-9e21-def90a8615a9&displaylang=en

Comment: Thanks - that's what I'm trying to upgrade to.  I should make the title clearer.

Comment: What you're trying to do was likely never supported in the first place.  If you're essentially trying to hook how static content is served, don't go through the WebForms view engine to pull this off.

What exactly are you trying to do?  Why do you need a filter to pull this off?

Comment: Why do you think it's not supported?  And we're not going through the view engine - we're simply looking at the rendered results.  The point is that this change breaks even simple filtering, like this example: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120308-1.aspx.  You can basically never set the filter property.

Comment: Also, I have no qualms refactoring the old code to use a different methodology if we have to.  I guess my question is - "why is this happening, and is it permanent, and is there a workaround?"

Comment: Filtering the response is allowed in general, but not from within a view itself.  The only time that Response.UsingHttpWriter = false is after the view has already started executing, at which time it's too late to set a filter (hence the 'unsupported' comment).  If you do this earlier in the pipeline, it should work.  Can you provide a stack trace so that we can see what step of the MVC pipeline is active when this exception occurs?

Comment: @Levi - ah, I misunderstood "going through the View engine".  Yes, this is all happening during ViewPage.Render - our equivalent of the "script manager" calls a render method on itself to generate the combined CSS and javascript content (if not cached) and output the URL to the minified/combined CSS and javascript.  

We use a capturing filter in order to grab content that exists in alligator tags that are part of the script registrations.  It's actually quite elegant to use - but what I'm hearing is that it will no longer be possible to do this?

Comment: Correct.  Installing a response filter from within the view itself is not supported, nor is it intended to be supported in the future.  Views in MVC are literally meant to be dumb HTML templating systems.  You could consider having an action filter (override OnResultExecuting / OnResultExecuted) which installs your response filter.  This moves that particular logic out of the view.

Comment: @Levi - thanks for the update.  If you wanted to move a summary of your comments into an answer, I'd be happy to give you +25 for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Views in MVC, unlike regular .aspx pages, are meant to be treated as HTML templating systems.  The problem here stems from the fact that that *after the view had already started executing*, the page tried to install a response filter in order to manipulate the HTML being sent to the client.

The solution in this case is to move the response filter installation to an earlier part of the MVC pipeline.  For example, using a custom action filter, you can override the OnResultExecuting() method to install your custom response filter.  This moves the installation out of the view and doesn't violate the principle of simple HTML-only views.